# Adding many raster tiles to geopackage

Tags: qgis, raster, geopackage

I have many raster tiles (in tif format, SR WGS84) and, since all together are very heavy, I want to unify them in a geopackage.

I've tried to do that in QGIS, performing the following steps:

1. converting all the raster in PNG format,
2. creating a geopackage from the Browser panel (Create Database > No geometry)
3. simply dragging them into the geopackage created ---> Import succesful

but: the original rasters have a single band, while once added to the geopackage they have **4** bands.

Is there a way to create a Geopackage that contains all my raster tiles (about 850 tiles) maintaining only the 1 original band?

Comment: Could you share some test data?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've edited the question being more focused, could you re-open it, please?

Answer (score 3):

Create with your 850 raster tiles a VRT ("Raster" -> "Other" -> "Build Virtual Raster"). Remove the tick from the checkbox "Place each input file into a seperate band". You can leave the other options as they are. Drag & Drop the VRT within QGIS into the Geopackage you prepared - Done

(or rightclick on the VRT, "export as" -> Geopackage )

Comment: The issue wasn't solved: once created the virtual raster, it has got one single band with original values. But after I export it as geopackage, it contains 4 bands, of which one contains a NoData value, while the other three contain the same value, that I think is an interpolation of neighbouring cells.

Comment: What is the data type of your source data? 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit?

Comment: It is eight-bit unsigned integer. I don't understand why the output raster in the geopackage has different cells values from the input.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy with gdalwarp (2.4 and newer):

```
gdalwarp -of GPKG inputfolder\*.tif output.gpkg
gdaladdo -r cubic output.gpkg
```

If your source data is single band 8 bit grayscale, then the tiles in the GeoPackage will be likewise.

However, the GDAL GeoPackage driver will by default expose a GeoPackage dataset as four bands RGBA. This means that even though your gpkg file contains single band tiles, it will appear to have four bands when opening it in (for instance) gdalinfo or QGIS. To be absolutely sure, you can

1. Open the GeoPackage in DB browser for SQLite
2. Open the tile table (named after the file)
3. Sort by zoom_level
4. Pick a row from the highest zoom level, save tile_data cell as a jpg.
5. Inspect the jpg in a GIS or drawing application

The tiles around the edges of the dataset will be 4 band PNG, but all other tiles should be single band 8 bit.