# What is a good way to store a large (tiled) geo raster?

Tags: file-geodatabase, large-datasets, geopackage

**I have a large geotiff raster map (after compression 88 GB) as a series of 919 geotiff-tiles. How can I turn these into a practical file solution (e.g. one file) that allows me to efficiently work with the whole map?**

Having a lot of tile-files is only useful, if one needs just a small part of the tiles and there is an easy way to identify and find the corresponding tiles/files - which is not the case for me. If one needs the whole map (e.g. as baselayer), adding/styling >900 tiles is not practical and much more circumstancial than handling one file.

However one 88 GB file is very clunky and may cause crashes when used for calculations/processing (as some tools want to cache the whole file in order to process it).

I have used geodatabases before, which seem to have intelligent reading behavior (only cache/load the parts of the map that are visible), allow for pyramids for different zoom levels etc.
How can I create a local file / geodb, that allows for these features? (I prefer QGIS/GDAL, but ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro answers work as well). Is gpkg the way to go? Or local geoDB files? Are there respective pros and cons? And how do I create these?

I didn't find a good overview, just a [how-to question for gpkg](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347117/adding-many-raster-tiles-to-geopackage), so I was hoping there is some insight about the topic in the community.